# Proving some properties of pointwise convergent sequences.

Tags: real-analysis

It is given that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwisely on a domain $D$ and $g_n\rightarrow g$ pointwisely on $D$.

I'm trying to prove these two properties:

1. $f_ng_n\rightarrow fg$ pointwisely on $D$
2. $|f_n|\rightarrow |f|$ pointwisely on $D$

So I know $\forall x\in D, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_f>0$ such that $|f_n-f|<\epsilon  ,\forall n\leq N_f$ and $\exists N_g$ such that $|g_n-g|<\epsilon,\forall n \leq N_g$.

But looking at $|f_ng_n-fg|$, I need to manipulate this somehow so that I can use the triangle inequality if I'm correct. I've tried using $f_n=(f_n-f)+f$ and $g_n=(g_n-g)+g$ and this gives me:

$|(f_n-f)(g_n-g) +g(f_n-f) + f(g_n-g) -fg|$

This seems to be where I want to go but the $fg$ at the end is causing me problems.

For the second one, we're looking at $||f_n|-|f||$. I don't really know what I'm doing with this. I thought it should be pretty easy but I must be missing something because I just don't know what to do.

If anyone has time, a bit of help would be preferred to a straight up answer. But either would be really useful.

And a final note, assuming I figure out the second proof, would proving the same thing under uniform convergence be similar to this one using pointwise convergence?

Comment: For the first one note that $f_ng_n-fg = (f_n-f)(g_n-g)+f(g_n-g)+g(f_n-f)$

Comment: If I choose to do it this way, what happens to the $-fg$ that I mentioned?

Comment: Well you use this identity (which can be checked directly) and then use the triangle inequality. Remember, to show that $f_n\to f$ pointwise one must show that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ for all $x$. So using the fact that $f_n\to f$ and $g_n\to g$ pointwise, and using this identity will show that $|f_ng_n(x)-fg(x)|\to 0$ for all $x$

Comment: OH. So instead of what I was trying to do, I can show the identity you gave directly. And from there it seems to be straightforward. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is pointwise convergence, it suffices to prove the results for sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ which converge to $x$ and $y$ respectively, in $\mathbb{C}$ (I guess...).

The second one simply requires the [reverse triangular inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality): $||x_n|-|y_n||\leq |x_n-y_n|$.

For the first one, write
$$
|x_ny_n-xy|=|x_ny_n-x_ny+x_ny-xy|\leq |x_n||y_n-y|+|y||x_n-x|.
$$
And don't forget to use that a converging sequence is bounded. So there is $M>0$ such that $|x_n|\leq M$ for all $n$. I think you can conclude.

Comment: Okay, so $|x_n||y_n-y|+|y||x_n-x| \leq M\epsilon + |y| \epsilon = \epsilon(M+|y|)$? And then we could take $\alpha=\frac{\epsilon}{M+|y|}$, so $\forall \epsilon >0, \alpha <\epsilon$ and then we're done. I think this makes sense. Some of it comes from a similar proof using sequences I did before.

Comment: Almost. You want $|x_n-x|\leq \epsilon/2|y|$ (unless $y=0$ which case you treat separately) and $|y_n-y|\leq \epsilon/2M$.

Comment: @MangoPirate Or you use the identity given by Leon. It makes things easier. But the trick is slightly harder to remember. That's the price to pay.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I understand what we're doing now. Both ways work, I think it's helpful to have seen both of these.

Comment: @MangoPirate Leon's way is more elegant. But it takes a little more time to get the formula right. While the trick $0=-x_ny+x_ny$ is standard in analysis, so you get it right away. But again, Leon's approach is more elegant.